# Programmatically created form not displaying form_set_error feedback

Tags: 7, forms

I've seen plenty of people ask a similar question but none of them are doing what I'm doing.

I have form function in my theme (mytheme_whatever_form()) with validation and submission handlers. I then put a placeholder in the body of a page like |*my-placeholder*| and a module I created there is a hook that parses the body of a node for anything with the pattern |*whatever*| and replaces hyphens with underscores and prefixes it with the theme name and executes that function if it exists (so it would execute mytheme_my_placeholder() from my example).

Inside mytheme_my_placeholder() I am rendering the output of mytheme_whatever_form() to place the form on my page.

When doing it this way I get the form on the page like I want and the validation and submission handlers work but no form_set_error or drupal_set_message calls return messages.

I can call whatever functions I want in the handlers and they execute as expected, except for anything that generates a status/error message.

This is very likely due to the way I'm loading the form but I can't find a good reason for it. form_set_error and drupal_set_message should both put a message into the system that is displayed via the page template and shouldn't care one bit what I'm doing with any other content on the page.

What am I overlooking and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Most likely the hook you're using is called too late for messages to be added. Inside which hook are you replacing the placeholders with the form? Also have you looked at custom text filters? See [here](http://pingv.com/blog/drupal-text-formats-102-developing-custom-filters)

Comment: are you sure the form_set_error is being called? do you see the message in a dpm of $messages for example? if yes and you see the message in the dpm, then can try accessing and displaying the messages from inside the form instead of from the page, since the form is probably built/rebuilt after the page is created.

Comment: @Beebee: hook_node_view()

Comment: @longboardnode: The validation function is being called and the conditional I wrapped around the form_set_error is validating to true. When I have the function die there it does. That leads me to believe that form_set_error is being executed. I would expect a WSoD if there was a problem with the function or a system log of the problem otherwise but I get neither. I also tried adding $form['#prefix'] .= theme('status_messages'); but still don't see messages.

Comment: hmmm weird! sounds like you're doing all the right things... can you try this: 
`$form = drupal_get_form('your_form');
print theme('status_messages');
print drupal_render($form);` and see if the messages display?

Comment: another question: is there a reason your form is in your theme as opposed to a custom module? I believe theme functions (as opposed to module functions) get called quite late in the game and that might affect things...

Comment: Using the suggested code doesn't seem to make any impact. I should also mention that the form doesn't highlight empty required fields or anything either but I am more concerned about the messages not being displayed. As for why I'm doing it this way, it's easier to maintain the code if it's contained in the theme as opposed to being split between theme and module(s). I also hate the webform module, especially when the data from the form doesn't need to be stored, in case you were wondering why I don't use it instead. :)

Comment: I just moved the form to a module and tested it. Exact same problem. So I got curious and looked at a function I have in a separate module that is meant to strip out certain status messages (product added to cart and such). Commented out that function and I get my status messages back. So there's something wrong with that function. However, that doesn't explain why the form fields with errors aren't highlighting.

Comment: glad you found the offending function which masked the messages. Re errored fields not being highlighted, can you share form_set_error code?

Comment: I'm using: form_set_error('old','Unable to validate your current password.');
The field name is "old" and it's a part of a group of fields under 'password_fields' but I do not have tree=TRUE. Despite that I have also tried password_fields][old with no success.

Comment: Are you sure your form element is not receiving the `error` class? Or is it a case of your CSS file not highlighting elements with class `error` with a red border? This can happen if you don't include the system css files.

Comment: Seems like it's both. While messing with the code inspector I added the error class to the field but it didn't do anything, then I noticed that I have a style set to remove the border. However, my class wasn't the issue since it isn't setting the error class to begin with. Now I have added a :not(error) on my class so the border isn't removed on errored fields, I just need to figure out why it's not setting the error class on those fields.

Comment: @JasonGray can you test it on another non-tree field (or can you add a test one) to see if the error messaging is working in general?

Comment: It's already not a tree. What I was doing to test is just leaving everything blank and hitting submit. All fields are required so they should all highlight along with the error message. Error messages are working again after fixing my message filtering code but the fields aren't being highlighted. It doesn't seem to be setting the "error" class on those fields for some reason.